# Safest file permissions for samba access

Tags: permissions, samba, acl

I have set a samba user (say, `remoteuser`) who is supposed to manipulate files under some system folders on the samba server (i.e. and not only his home directory's files), such as e.g. `/etc/somedir`)

The dir now is under `root:root` ownership

In order to follow the safest approach, what is the preferred way of going about permission assignments?

One way (I guess) would be to create a group (e.g. `sambagroup`), and add both `remoteuser` and `root` to this group?

this does not seem to work probably due to`etc`'s ownership of `root:root`.

Should I prefer `acl` and add the necessary permissions to `remoteuser` directly to `/etc/somedir`?

**edit1**: pls note (although it goes without saying) that `remoteuser` is both the `samba` and the system (`debian`) username for the particular user.

**edit2**: for some reason these commands do not help either:

```
sudo setfacl -Rm u:remoteuser:rwx /etc/somedir
sudo setfacl -Rdm u:remoteuser:rwx /etc/somedir
```

**edit3**: I would like file editing to take place on the workstation of the remote user, by letting him open a file via a text editor (e.g. `gedit`)

Comment: Samba is probably not the right too for system files manipulation.

Comment: Samba is not the tool to do this. You do this over ssh and the admin user account so a user needs to use "sudo". Nothing else. No messing with /etc/ or whatever on Ubuntu. " I would like file editing to take place on the workstation of the remote user, by letting him open a file via a text editor (e.g. gedit)" No you do not want this... really not. The times I have seen people using Word as an editor for a Linux file and ****** a file up....

Comment: ok many thanks ... point taken ... ssh and good ol' `vim` ... :)

Comment: When it is about config files: nano is good too ;-) I myself code software on windows in aptana and then use ssh to copy it over to linux. And and regarding the last part last comment: samba does NOT do carriagereturn/linefeed <> linefeed conversion ;-)